# Can two different programs connect to one LevelDB same time?

Tags: leveldb

If yes, how to do this?
When I am trying to connect to db used by another program I am getting `OpenError: IO error: lock ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form DB documentation

"A database may only be opened by one process at a time. The leveldb implementation acquires a lock from the operating system to prevent misuse."

Please find more info here

https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/182

Possible solution

https://github.com/juliangruber/multilevel